# How would I initialize a dictionary

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Say I have such a dictionary in my `class`:

```
entities: { [id: string]: string}
```

I am trying to assign the values this way:

```
this.entities = [
  {['xyz']: 'string1' },
  {['qaz']: 'string2' } 
]
```

Just didn't work that way. Can you help to figure out?

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
this.entities = [
    { xyz: 'string1' },
    { qaz: 'string2' } 
]
```